# How to escape backslash bracket (\[) in Markdown?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

How does one escape the "backslash square brackets" \[ \] sequence in Markdown for GitHub?
The sequence produces a `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` section.

This is only a problem with Markdown for GitHub. I can write it here without the problem:

\[something \]

This code in GitHub will however produce

\
    something

Comment: Having the same problem with Markdown files processed through [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/); the selected solution works, fortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now fixed on GitHub. So there is no need to escape square brackets anymore. To type `[some text]`, you could just type:

```
// your markdown
[some text]
```

This is good for two reasons:

1. square brackets are no longer parsed separately from figure and hyper-links.
2. This means that we could use `\]` and `\[` for display latex math, which is the correct way to write LaTeX. ($$ is not a LaTeX command and should never be used.)

You can check this by editing the README.md of a GitHub project.

Answer (score 53):

This has been fixed on github.com.  I'm not sure when, but you can now escape square brackets with a single backlash. EG

```
\[Hello\]
```

is rendered as

[Hello]

Comment: This is in the original Markdown definition, so this was a weakness of GitHub Markdown: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash

Answer (score 38):

I have resorted to surrounding my bracketed string with backticks:
`[[320,50],[300,250]]`

Which turns it into: 
`[[320,50],[300,250]]` So now my array doesn't turn into a link.

Comment: Yes, the backtick do the job. Thanks.
BTW, the problem I stated was not how to escape brackets but "backslash brackets" (`\[`) as occurs in many bash scripts. Backticks do stop Github markdown from trying to perform any transformation.

Comment: GitHub has fixed this problem with the original Markdown definition (https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash), and we can now use the standard `\[` and `\]` (instead of switching to code mode with backticks).

Comment: You can also use the HTML entity numbers `&#91;` & `&#93;` for `[` & `]` respectively. e.g. `&#91;320,50&#93;` but it's not very readable.

Answer (score 5):

just write:

```
This is a __backslash with a square bracket__: \\\[.
```

It works on github for me.

---

### Edit

Now that the question has been updated, here is an updated answer.
Just escape all characters, at the beginning and at the end:

`foo \\\[something\\\] bar`   will produce => `foo \[something\] bar`

Works normally on github:  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=oh2xyp&s=6

---

### Edit 2

Just tried on a wiki... you're right, it doesn't work there. I guess it's because of the special meaning that constructs like `[[foobar]]` have in the wiki syntax.
I'd say your best shot is this: `__\__ __[__ __something__ __\__ __]__` (without code backsticks).
Weirdly it doesn't work here, but it works on github wikis.

Still, if you think it's a bug, you should report it as they say [here](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown).

Comment: Sorry but this code still doesn't work for me. I created a wiki page, pasted in foo \\\[something\\\] bar and it still shows up with a <code> block added. Note that the GitHub Gist editor doesn't do that. It is only with Wiki pages (which use the GitHub flavored Markdown).

Comment: I've reported the bug to GitHub. Thanks for the link. I'll give you a point for your work but the answer is unfortunately that it can't be done.