# How to print special characters like ` , [] in the markdown cell as it is?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

When I type characters like `[]`  or  `` ` `` in the markdown cell, it processes those as links, inline code etc. Is there any way to print it as the special characters itself?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this question is specifically related to `jupyter-notebook`, but for markdown alone, you can use `\[` to resolve this issue, like this: [not link](not referenced to anything).

This question is already being answered here on StackOverflow:

- [How to escape backslash bracket ([) in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027723/how-to-escape-backslash-bracket-in-markdown)

You can also find plenty of reference on plenty of references and resources, like [MARKDOWN SYNTAX - GitHub](https://guides.github.com/pdfs/markdown-cheatsheet-online.pdf).

Some extra information can also be found here on StackExchange:

- [How do I escape a backtick ` within in-line code in Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-within-in-line-code-in-markdown)

For Jupyter notebook, you can follow the instruction on their official documentation:

- [MyST Markdown overview](https://jupyterbook.org/content/myst.html)

As per in their documentation:

> In addition to CommonMark Markdown, Jupyter Book also supports a more fully-featured version of Markdown called **MyST Markdown**. This is a superset of CommonMark that includes syntactic pieces that are useful for publishing computational narratives. For more information about MyST Markdown, see MyST Markdown overview.